# DoCmd.RunSQL Use Transaction?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, methods

What does it mean to "use transactions" in the case of the DoCmd.RunSQL method?  I've searched high and low, SO and Google, and can't find a simple explanation.  Apparently I don't understand what transactions are, and how I should choose TRUE or FALSE here.  I'm running a query that uses a pass-through query to append records to an existing table in the Access file

Comment: Transactions are a group of actions that can affect multiple recordsets which can be rolled back.  Here is a link.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb243806(v=office.12).aspx